# SQL Server Data Tools Install Failure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to update a new installation of Visual Studio 2015. I am attempting to install the SQL Server Data Tools update, but am getting 'Setup Failed'. I have tried restarting, repairing the .Net Framework, reinstalling the C++ 86,64 packages. Nothing has worked.

[Setup Failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv45k.png)

Comment: You get no error message?

Comment: Just the Setup Failed error. I'm at a loss at this point.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv45k.png

Comment: SSDT, Visual Studio installs are a complete mess and very easy to break. I suggest you take a look in `%temp%` and see if there are any install logs in there that give any more info.